# Android Activity Lifecycle in React Native - ViewPager

Tags: android, react-native

I've only recently learnt Android with the help of some textbooks but am not well versed and am currently exploring React Native. Building off this, I'm curious if the SO community can help.

- What happens to the activity/fragment lifecycle in React Native? Do we only have one activity alive for one React Native app?
- As an example, in the instance of a tabbed ViewPager, in Android we'd have Fragments being pulled in and out of life (onpause, onresume) - each page with it's own methods, and behavior. In React Native [(See React Native ViewPager)](https://github.com/madhu314/react-native-tabbed-view-pager-android), are these views operating the exact same ? Or is React Native more "simulating" the experience of a tabbed ViewPager, without the real tabs implmentation - almost like how Hybrid Web Apps work?
- If there are no lifecycle methods, React Native effectively uses props, and bridges, to "simulate" the logic - but would essentially have one Activity running the javascript thread for these various views?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So it's been a while since looking into this, and since I've been able to learn a lot about React Native!

For all intensive purposes, it helps to think of React Native as a single page app which happens within one React Activity -> I'm not sure if this is what happens in reality, but yes, it starts off as a React activity class, and all of the injection of modules and other is introduced throughout the lifecycle.